# How to deal with array of string features in traditional machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

## Problem

Let's say we have a dataframe that looks like this:

```sql
age  job         friends                                    label
23   'engineer'  ['World of Warcraft', 'Netflix', '9gag']   1
35   'manager'   NULL                                       0
...
```

If we are interested in training a classifier that predicts *label* using *age*, *job*, and *friends* as features, how would we go about transforming the features into a numerical array which can be fed into a model?

- Age is pretty straightforward since it is already numerical.
- Job can be hashed / indexed since it is a categorical variable.
- Friends is a list of categorical variables. How would I go about representing this feature?

## Approaches:

Hash each element of the list. Using the example dataframe, let's assume our hashing function has the following mapping:

```sql
NULL                -> 0
engineer            -> 42069
World of Warcraft   -> 9001
Netflix             -> 14
9gag                -> 9
manager             -> 250
```

Let's further assume that the maximum length of friends is 5. Anything shorter gets zero-padded on the right hand side. If friends size is larger than 5, then the first 5 elements are selected.

### Approach 1: Hash and Stack

dataframe after feature transformation would look like this:

```sql
feature                             label
[23, 42069, 9001, 14, 9, 0, 0]      1
[35, 250,   0,    0,  0, 0, 0]      0
```

#### Limitations

Consider the following:

```sql
age  job           friends                                        label
23   'engineer'    ['World of Warcraft', 'Netflix', '9gag']       1
35   'manager'      NULL                                          0
26   'engineer'    ['Netflix', '9gag', 'World of Warcraft']       1
...
```

Compare the features of the first and third record:

```sql
feature                             label
[23, 42069, 9001, 14, 9, 0, 0]      1
[35, 250,   0,    0,  0, 0, 0]      0
[26, 42069, 14,    9, 9001, 0]      1
```

Both records have the same set of friends, but are ordered differently resulting in a different feature hashing even though they should be the same.

### Approach 2: Hash, Order, and Stack

To solve the limitation of Approach 1, simply order the hashes from the *friends* feature. This  would result in the following feature transform (assuming descending order):

```sql
feature                             label
[23, 42069, 9001, 14, 9, 0, 0]      1
[35, 250,   0,    0,  0, 0, 0]      0
[26, 42069, 9001, 14, 9, 0, 0]      1
```

This approach has a limitation too. Consider the following:

```sql
age  job           friends                                        label
23   'engineer'    ['World of Warcraft', 'Netflix', '9gag']       1
35   'manager'      NULL                                          0
26   'engineer'    ['Netflix', '9gag', 'World of Warcraft']       1
42   'manager'     ['Netflix', '9gag']                            1
...
```

Applying feature transform with ordering we get:

```sql
row  feature                             label
1    [23, 42069, 9001, 14, 9, 0, 0]      1
2    [35, 250,   0,    0,  0, 0, 0]      0
3    [26, 42069, 9001, 14, 9, 0, 0]      1
4    [44, 250, 14, 9, 0, 0, 0]           1
```

What is the problem with the above features? Well, the hashes for Netflix and 9gag in rows 1 and 3 have the same index in the array but not in row 4. This would mess up with the training.

### Approach 3: Convert Array to Columns

What if we convert *friends* into a set of 5 columns and deal with each of the resulting columns just like we deal with any categorical variable?

Well, let's assume the *friends* vocabulary size is large (>100k). It would then be madness to go and create >100k columns where each column is responsible for the hash of the respective vocab element.

### Approach 4: One-Hot-Encoding and then Sum

How about this? Convert each hash to one-hot-vector, and add up all these vectors.

In this  case, the feature in row one for example would look like this:

```
[23, 42069, 01x8, 1, 01x4, 1, 01x8986, 1, 01x(max_hash_size-8987)]
```

Where 0<sup>1x8</sup> denotes a row of 8 zeros.

The problem with this approach is that these vectors will be very huge and sparse.

### Approach 5: Use Embedding Layer and 1D-Conv

With this approach, we feed each word in the friends array to the embedding layer, then convolve. Similar to the Keras IMDB example: https://keras.io/examples/imdb_cnn/

Limitation: requires using deep learning frameworks. I want something which works with traditional machine learning. I want to do logistic regression or decision tree.

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I am currently investigating sparse data representation and I think that might be useful to deal with Approach 4's limitation

Comment: It is possible, in a couple of lines of Python, to use a pre-trained word embedding to convert your list of words to a list of vectors. This opens up further ways of preparing the data for use in a traditional ML model, but does it fit your criterion 'works with traditional machine learning'? No need to train a neural net, but you do need to import (e.g.) tensorflow to do the embedding. I can flesh this out to a proper answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 3):

As another answer mentioned, you've already listed a number of alternatives that could work, depending on the dataset and the model and such.

For what it's worth, a typical logistic regression model that I've encountered would use Approach 3, and convert each of your friends strings into a binary feature. If you're opposed to having 100k features, you could treat these features like a bag-of-words model and discard the stopwords (very common features).

I'll also throw a hashing variant into the mix:

[**Bloom Filter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)

You could store the strings in question in a bloom filter for each training example, and use the bits of the bloom filter as a feature in your logistic regression model. This is basically a hashing solution like you've already mentioned, but it takes care of some of the indexing/sorting issues, and provides a more principled tradeoff between sparsity and feature uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no definitive answer to this problem, you presented 5 alternatives, and the five are valid, it all depends on the dataset you are using.

Considering this, I will list the options that I find most advantageous. For me option 5 is the best, but as in your case you want to use traditional machine learning techniques, I will discard it. So I would go for option 4, but in this case I need to know if you have the hardware to deal with this problem, if the answer is yes, I would go with this option, considering the answer is no, i would try approach 2, as you pointed out, the hashes for Netflix and 9gag in rows 1 and 3 have the same index in the array, but not in row 4, but that won't be a problem if you have enough data for training ( again, it all depends on the data available ), even if I have some problems with this approach, I would apply a Data Augmentation technique before discarding it.

Option 1 seems to me the worst, in it you have a great chance of overfitting and certainly a use of a lot of computational resources.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1 (Hash and Stack) and 2 (Hash, Order, and Stack) resolve their limitations if the result of the hashing function is considered as the index of a sparse vector with values of 1 instead of the values of each position of the vector.

Then, whenever "World of Warcraft" is in `friends` array, the feature vector will have a value of 1 in position 9001, regardless of the position of "World of Warcraft" in `friends` array (limitation of approach 1) and regardless of the existence of other elements in `friends` array (limitation of approach 2). If "World of Warcraft" is not in `friends` array, then the value of features vector in position 9001 will most likely be 0 (look up hashing trick collisions to learn more).

Answer (score 0):

Using word2vec representation (as a feature value), then do a supervised classification also can be a good idea.